# convert json string to string array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string, serialization

I'm trying to convert a json string to a string array

my json string: `"[\"false\",\"true\"]"`

```
var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string[] strArray = new string[2];
strArray = js.Deserialize("[\"false\",\"true\"]", string[2]).ToArray();
```

but it only allows me to do a charArray.

I just need to be able to call my result as `strArray[0]` so that it will return `"false"`

Comment: What type is `js`?

Comment: editted question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
strArray = js.Deserialize<string[]>("[\"false\",\"true\"]");
```

Comment: man, the only option I didnt test I assume..
thanks, I will accept as answer once I am allowed to

Answer (score 1):

Your example code wouldn't compile. The second parameter should be a `Type` object, which `string[2]` isn't. It should be this:

```
strArray = js.Deserialize("[\"false\",\"true\"]", typeof(string[]));
```

Or, as the other answer mentioned, you can use [the other, generic overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserialize#System_Web_Script_Serialization_JavaScriptSerializer_Deserialize__1_System_String_) for the method:

```
strArray = js.Deserialize<string[]>("[\"false\",\"true\"]");
```

Either one will do exactly the same thing. It's just handy to be able to pass a `Type` object sometimes if you don't know beforehand what the actual type will be. In this case you do, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: ```js.Deserialize(..., typeof(T))``` and ```jsDeserialize<T>(...)``` would behave the same, no?

Comment: @Lukas Yes, they do.

Comment: Sorry, just a little confused about the `It's just handy to be able to pass a Type object sometimes if you don't know beforehand what the actual type will be`

Comment: You will know when you need it :) It's hard to explain a real use case... but you can, for example, do something like `js.Deserialize(..., someObject.GetType())` without knowing beforehand what type `someObject` is (you just know the JSON is the same type). You cannot do that with `Deserialize<T>()`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Newtonsoft's JArray type?  It is built for this conversion and can handle many edge cases automatically.

```
var jArray = JArray.Parse("[\"false\",\"true\"]");
var strArray = jArray.ToObject<string[]>()
```

This will give you a string array.  But you could also elect to use `.ToArray()` to convert to a JToken array which can sometimes be more useful.